# Is it possible to do price breaks in Woocommerce using actual prices ( not discounts)?

Tags: wordpress, ecommerce, woocommerce

I am looking for some way to do set price breaks in Woocommerce.

---

**Eg**

```
- item price = X
- more than 10 items in the cart the per unit price becomes Y
- more than 20 items in the cart the per unit price becomes Z
```

... these rules would then apply to every product, with each product having a 10 item price and a 20 item price.

---

I know it's posible to do something like this using various plugins that allow various forms of **discounts** — but I need it to be based on **flat prices** as the product catalog will be managed via CSV and the already existing large CSV file cant be easily changed - and that file is structured along the lines of:

- **Unit Price** — X
- **> 10 Units Price** — Y
- **> 20 Units Price** — Z

So I would need the products to be in that structure ( as opposed to )

- **Unit Price** — X
- **> 10 Units Price** — less some percent or fixed amount
- **etc**

Ideally I'd like a plugin to do this rather than coding it but I have searched and every plugin I've found seems to use the discount model. Some of them offer flat and fixed discounts but none that I've found allow me to type in an actual volume discount price on a per product basis.

**Does anyone know of a plugin which can achieve this, or any other way to do it.** If I have to code it I will consider it but I'd prefer not since there's some management of that code going forward and we don't really have time to build a plugin right now.

Comment: sorry - I thought that was OK to ask here - I knew it was off topic for the developer forum but it doesn't make much sense to me for a webmaster forum - I never would have expected that - the majority of webmasters I deal with would try to do as much as possible using plugins - so is there another place this could be asked that you know of - or maybe it could be migrated - or maybe it's OK to talk about plugins here just not ask for advice for some reason - if you know that reason or have a linkt to a meta question it would be helpful - I had a search through the first page of results to no ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered two plugins that can achieve this:

1. **Dynamic Pricing** from WooCommerce https://woocommerce.com/products/dynamic-pricing/
2. **Wholesale Pro Suite** from Ignitewoo http://ignitewoo.com/woocommerce-extensions-plugins-themes/woocommerce-wholesale-pro-suite/